# How to debug when there are no errors

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, debugging

I installed a new onestep checkout module and it works fine but my charity donation module doesn't work now. When I get to the second step (actually its like a three step checkout). Anyway, it just keeps loading, the loader spinner just keeps spinning, but no javascript errors, no php errors --nothing. I have `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`.

How can I can I find what is the trouble?

Thanks

Comment: Try using chrome developer tools and see the AJAX request content

Comment: Okay I didn't think about that. I'll give it a try with my limited debugging knowledge. : ) Thanks

Comment: Nothing complex, just press F12, go to network and select XHR

Comment: This guide will help. Although not for the sane section, tge way to use chrome to debug it is the same. http://support.proxiblue.com.au/kb/faq.php?id=14